# dd-backup of corrupted disk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, dd, fsck

I used `dd` to create a imagefile of a partition of my external hdd.  I used the `'conv=noerror,sync'` option to skip readerrors and it did a full copy.

```
'sudo dd if=/dev/sdd of="/media/me/out/theimage.img" conv=noerror,sync'
```

Now I noticed that `fsck` returns some errors on the source-disk `/dev/sdd`. I had fsck repair the disk, which went well.

Now the question is: Should I make a new imagefile? Could it be that `dd` missed some data due to corrupted filesystem or some such?

Or can I use fsck to fix the imagefile just like it fixed the disk?

Right now if I run fsck on the image file, it screams at me that there are issues with the filesystem...

Answer (score 1):

You can do either: fix the image file or make a new one.

*However,*  I would use `ddrescue` instead of `dd` as it was *designed* to be able to read bad sectores / skip over them / ...:

```
sudo apt install gddrescue
ddrescue --retry-passes=3 /dev/sdd /media/me/out/theimage.img /media/me/out/theimage.log
```

For more info: [`man ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html)

Comment: Thanks. Ironically, ddrescue hangs on me...

log:
    # current_pos  current_status  current_pass
    0x6F3170000     ?               1
    #      pos        size  status
    0x00000000  0x6F3180000  +
    0x6F3180000  0xD4C6E80000  ?

Comment: Read *all of the documentation*: you have a bad sector and it doesn't hang: it's trying to continue...

Comment: How long can that take though? It's been stuck for at least 15 min. I'll let it run overnight.